# (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'loggedUser' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

When I am trying to use loggedUser which is coming from getter inside mounded lifecycle method it throws the  (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'loggedUser' of undefined error.

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      loggedUser: 'auth/loggedUser',
      users: 'users/getAllUsers',
    }),
```

and inside the promise in mounted where I try to filter out the loggedUser

```
mounted() {
...
      .then(function(res) {
           this.groupedUsers = _.filter(res, function(groupedUser) {
            return groupedUser.userId !== this.loggedUser.userId;
          });
}
```

it throws the error in the following line.

How can be it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The error says `Cannot read property 'loggedUser' of undefined`. Your code says `this.loggedUser`, so I assume that `this` is undefined. Try sending `this` to it.

Common trope used to be `that = this` in the outer context (inside mounted), or by sending it as an argument to the function (inside .then fn), though the more modern and simpler way is to simply use an arrow function `() => {}` which allow you to access the outer scope in this example.

Either way, `console.log(this)` until you have its reference. The problem is not having `this` in scope.

Comment: So the main issue is promisses? Because on the other parts of the page this refers either getter or data. Also do you mean simply in the mounted place let that = this?

Comment: and then use this freely inside promisse

Comment: Yup. The problem is more specifically scope, which is lost in promise fn.

Answer (score 0):

Always Use arrow functions to don't lose the context

```
mounted() {
...
      .then((res) => {
           this.groupedUsers = _.filter(res, (groupedUser) => {
            return groupedUser.userId !== this.loggedUser.userId;
          });
}
```